# How to solve Kuznets curve growth model for the given differential equation?

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

### Context:

Using the Maddison project real GDP per capita dataset, I derived the following equation using least squares:
0.012406  + *0.005132*ln(g) - *0.006304*ln(g)**2

As I am trying to predict the GDP per capita until 2050 for different economic groups, I referenced this paper's methodology "Tilman et al. 10.1073/pnas.1116437108" as to how they tried solving the same as a differential equation: dG/dt = G(-0.6284 + 0.157lnG - 0.0093ln(G)^2

I transformed my least squares the same way: -0.012406*g  + g*0.005132*math.log(g) - g*0.006304*math.log(g)**2

I am trying to solve the ODE in python for several initial values to get the Kuznets curve and estimate for 2050. I used the below code, but I am unable to solve the same.

### Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp 
import math

def solveit(y0):
    def gdp(g, t):
        y = g
        dgdt = [-0.012406*g  + g*0.005132*math.log(g) - g*0.006304*math.log(g)**2]
        return dgdt

#initial conditions
    #y0 = [785.60] 
    t = np.linspace(0, 60000, 1000)
#call integrator
    sol = odeint(gdp, y0, t)
    m = sol[:]
    plt.plot(t,m)
    plt.show()


ys= [[785.60],[1860],[7800]]

fig = plt.figure()
for y_ in ys:
    solveit(y_)

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

### Error message:

```
RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2.
```

---

Directions regarding the same would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like you need to fix the indentation of the code.   Check which lines are supposed to be inside the function `solveit`.

Answer (score 1):

When `odeint` calls the `func` parameter provided by the user, it will pass in an array for the state vector `y`.  Even when the system is a single scalar equation, `y` will be passed in as a 1-d array with length 1.  In your case, that means `g` will be a 1-d with length 1.  You have this in `gdp`:

```
    dgdt = [-0.012406*g  + g*0.005132*math.log(g) - g*0.006304*math.log(g)**2]
    return dgdt
```

The problem is the extra brackets in the expression for `dgdt`.  `g` is already a 1-d array, and therefore so is `-0.012406*g`.  It turns out that `math.log(g)` actually returns a scalar, but a scalar plus a 1-d NumPy with length 1 does what you would expect, so in this case it doesn't cause a problem.  So the result of the full expression `-0.012406*g  + g*0.005132*math.log(g) - g*0.006304*math.log(g)**2` is also a 1-d NumPy array (with length 1).  When you wrap that result in brackets, you increase the "depth" of the data structure. In effect, you create a 2-d array (with trivial shape (1, 1)).  For example, in the following, `w` is a 1-d array with length 1:

```
In [23]: w = np.array([1.0])

In [24]: np.shape(w)
Out[24]: (1,)

In [25]: np.shape([w])
Out[25]: (1, 1)
```

Note that `[w]` has shape `(1, 1)`, i.e. it is a *2-d* array.  `odeint` expects a 1-d array to be returned by the user's function, but it gets a 2-d array from your function and raises an error.

The fix is simple: remove those brackets:

```
    def gdp(g, t):
        dgdt = -0.012406*g  + g*0.005132*math.log(g) - g*0.006304*math.log(g)**2
        return dgdt
```

(Note that I removed the line `y = g`, which served no purpose.)